# Using jquery to clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a bunch of tables, to which I would like to have an add/delete button for each. When the user clicks add, it should add a row to the respective table and delete the row as well. I was able to accomplish this by having jquery place html code directly into the table but since I have so many tables, it became very inefficient. I was thinking rather to create a function, which clones that row but I do not know how to go about this. I want to be able to call this function whenever I add/delete row for any table.

My html code (for only two of my 18 tables) is:

```
<div class="well">
<h4>1.1 Teaching</h4>
<small>Please add the courses taught during the calendar year.</small>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="table-responsive" id="table1_1">
  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="teaching">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th>Req'd or Elective</th>
        <th>Presentation Format<sup>*</sup></th>
        <th>%'age Taught</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="ia_table">
        <td><select class="form-control" name="courseTB1_0" id="course">
                                                               <option>Course</option>
                                                                <option>John</option>
                                                                <option>Mike</option>
                                                                <option>Mary</option>
                                                                <option>William</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sectionTB1_0" id="section" placeholder='Section' class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="sessionTB1_0" id="session">
                                                               <option>Session</option>
                                                                <option>Fall</option>
                                                                <option>Winter</option>
                                                                <option>Spring</option>
                                                                <option>Summer</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="reqElecTB1_0" id="reqElec">
                                                               <option>Select</option>
                                                                <option>Required</option>
                                                                <option>Elective</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="presentationTB1_0" id="presentation" placeholder="Format" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="percentageTB1_0" id="percentage" placeholder="%" class="form-control" /></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a id="add_row_ia" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Add Row</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8">
      <a id='delete_row_ia' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="well">
<h4>1.2 Supervision of Undergraduate Students, Graduate Students, Postdoctoral Fellows</h4>
<small>Include those who have completed their studies/research this year.
</small>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="table-responsive" id="table1_2">
  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="supervision">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type of Student</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Co-Supervisor(s) (if any)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="s_table">
        <td><input type="text" name="nameTB2_0" id="name" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="studentTB2_0" id="student">
                                                               <option>Type</option>
                                                                <option>Bachelors</option>
                                                                <option>Masters</option>
                                                                <option>Doctoral</option>
                                                                <option>Postdoctoral</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="startTB2_0" id="start"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cosupervisorTB2_0" id="cosupervisor" placeholder="Co-Supervisor" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- /.table-responsive -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a id="add_row_supervision" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Add Row</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8">
      <a id='delete_row_supervision' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
```

My Jquery Code looks like:

```
$("body").on('click', '#add_row_ia', function() {
  var tr = $('#teaching .ia_table:last');
  var clone = tr.clone();
  clone.find("input").val('');
  clone.find("select").val('');
  tr.after(clone);
});

$("body").on('click', '#delete_row_ia', function() {
  var rowCount = $('#teaching tr').length;
  if (rowCount > 2) {
    $('#teaching tr:last').remove();
  };
});

$("body").on('click', '#add_row_supervision', function() {
  var tr = $('#supervision .s_table:last');
  var clone = tr.clone();
  clone.find("input").val('');
  clone.find("select").val('');
  tr.after(clone);
});

$("body").on('click', '#delete_row_supervision', function() {
  var rowCount = $('#supervision tr').length;
  if (rowCount > 2) {
    $('#supervision tr:last').remove();
  };
});
```

Apologies for the incredibly long html and jquery code, I did shorten it from what it looks like right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you know about code snippets in stackoverflow?

Comment: use classes instead of ids .. use same class for Add buttons and same class for Remove buttons .. and use `$(this)` to determine the `table tr` you need to work with

Comment: not really, still a relatively new member to this community. But I could learn it and implement it, would that be a better way to ask this question?

Comment: @Muhammad take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/91mqcn47/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As I said in comment*

> use classes instead of ids .. use same class for Add buttons and same
>   class for Remove buttons .. and use $(this) to determine the table tr
>   you need to work with

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_row', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr:last');
  var clone = tr.clone();
  clone.find("input").val('');
  clone.find("select").val('');
  tr.after(clone);
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete_row', function() {
  var rowCount = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr').length;
  var tr = $(this).closest('.row').prev('table').find('tr:last');
  if (rowCount > 2) {
    tr.remove();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
<h4>1.1 Teaching</h4>
<small>Please add the courses taught during the calendar year.</small>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="table-responsive" id="table1_1">
  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="teaching">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th>Req'd or Elective</th>
        <th>Presentation Format<sup>*</sup></th>
        <th>%'age Taught</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="ia_table">
        <td><select class="form-control" name="courseTB1_0" id="course">
                                                               <option>Course</option>
                                                                <option>John</option>
                                                                <option>Mike</option>
                                                                <option>Mary</option>
                                                                <option>William</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sectionTB1_0" id="section" placeholder='Section' class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="sessionTB1_0" id="session">
                                                               <option>Session</option>
                                                                <option>Fall</option>
                                                                <option>Winter</option>
                                                                <option>Spring</option>
                                                                <option>Summer</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="reqElecTB1_0" id="reqElec">
                                                               <option>Select</option>
                                                                <option>Required</option>
                                                                <option>Elective</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="presentationTB1_0" id="presentation" placeholder="Format" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="percentageTB1_0" id="percentage" placeholder="%" class="form-control" /></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a id="add_row_ia" class="btn btn-primary pull-left add_row">Add Row</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8">
      <a id='delete_row_ia' class="pull-right btn btn-danger delete_row">Delete Row</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="well">
<h4>1.2 Supervision of Undergraduate Students, Graduate Students, Postdoctoral Fellows</h4>
<small>Include those who have completed their studies/research this year.
</small>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="table-responsive" id="table1_2">
  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="supervision">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type of Student</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Co-Supervisor(s) (if any)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="s_table">
        <td><input type="text" name="nameTB2_0" id="name" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="studentTB2_0" id="student">
                                                               <option>Type</option>
                                                                <option>Bachelors</option>
                                                                <option>Masters</option>
                                                                <option>Doctoral</option>
                                                                <option>Postdoctoral</option>
                                                            </select></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="startTB2_0" id="start"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cosupervisorTB2_0" id="cosupervisor" placeholder="Co-Supervisor" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- /.table-responsive -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a id="add_row_supervision" class="btn btn-primary pull-left add_row">Add Row</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8">
      <a id='delete_row_supervision' class="pull-right btn btn-danger delete_row">Delete Row</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
```